# For what value $p$ is $l_p$ not a norm or a metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Can someone please remind me for which values of $p \in [0, \infty)$ is the little $l_p$ norm or $l_p$ metric not a norm or a metric

I vaguely remember that $l_0$ norm is a not a norm. Could someone remind me of other ones?

Comment: do you have the triangle inequality $\|x+y\|_p \le \|x\|_p+\|y\|_p$ ? (try on a one dimensional vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$ "norm" fails to satisfy the triangle inequality for $p<1$.